# Can't add data to a specific route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routing-controllers

I'm new in server side and maybe understand the concept of adding data to db wrong. I want to add a user that comes from axios.post to specific groupId parameter but when I do get requests on the postman I see that it adds the user to all the groups I have but not only to the matched one in the route.

Here are the post and get handlers for the route:

```
router.get('/groups/:groupId/users',function(req,res, next){
Group.findOne({groupId: req.params.groupId}).then(function(group) {
User.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(15).then(function (user) {
    res.send(user);
}).catch(next);
})
```

});

```
router.post('/groups/:groupId/users', function(req, res, next){
Group.findOne({groupId: req.params.groupId}).then(function(group) {
    User.create(req.body).then(function (user) {
        res.send(user);
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

});

[all the groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sik8u.png)

[postman request as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHWCg.png)

[postman request shouldn't be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hngIm.png)

Comment: do you have groupId column in user table as a  foreign key ?

Comment: Not sure I understand how it will help in this case. I have a users reference column in the groups table